# What's the R equivalent of SQL's LIKE 'description%' statement?

Tags: sql, r, string, pattern-matching

Not sure how else to ask this but, I want to search for a term within several string elements. Here's what my code looks like (but wrong):

```
inplay = vector(length=nrow(des))
for (ii in 1:nrow(des)) {
 if (des[ii] = 'In play%')
  inplay[ii] = 1
 else inplay[ii] = 0
}
```

des is a vector that stores strings such as "Swinging Strike", "In play (run(s))", "In play (out(s) recorded)" and etc. What I want inplay to store is a 1s and 0s vector corresponding with the des vector, with the 1s in inplay indicating that the des value had "In play%" in it and 0s otherwise.

I believe the 3rd line is incorrect, because all this does is return a vector of 0s with a 1 in the last element.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The R analog to SQL's LIKE is just R's ordinary indexing syntax.

The 'LIKE' operator selects data rows from a table by matching string values in a specified column against a user-supplied pattern

```
> # create a data frame having a character column
> clrs = c("blue", "black", "brown", "beige", "berry", "bronze", "blue-green", "blueberry")
> dfx = data.frame(Velocity=sample(100, 8), Colors=clrs)
> dfx
            Velocity    Colors
        1       90       blue
        2       94      black
        3       71      brown
        4       36      beige
        5       75      berry
        6        2     bronze
        7       89    blue-green
        8       93    blueberry

> # create a pattern to use (the same as you would do when using the LIKE operator)
> ptn = '^be.*?'  # gets beige and berry but not blueberry
> # execute a pattern-matching function on your data to create an index vector
> ndx = grep(ptn, dfx$Colors, perl=T)
> # use this index vector to extract the rows you want from the data frome:
> selected_rows = dfx[ndx,]
> selected_rows
   Velocity Colors
     4       36  beige
     5       75  berry
```

In SQL, that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM dfx WHERE Colors LIKE ptn3
```

Comment: Why do you wrap `grep()` with `fnx`?

Comment: i originally had in mind a function that took the data frame as an argument, rather than just a 1D vector. In any event, edited to remove function wrapper.

Comment: This works, but suppose I want to store a 1 in vector inplay if the row number is contained in ndx, and a 0 otherwise, where the length of vector inplay is the length of dfx. How do I go about this?

I'm playing with IF and ELSE statements but I'm not getting this to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured it out. Suppose SL is the matrix that stores "Swinging Strike", "In play(run(s))" etc. 

ndx = grep('^In play.*?', SL$des, perl=T)
SL <- transform(SL, inplay=mat.or.vec(1,nrow(SL))[des])
SL$inplay <- replace(SL$inplay, ndx, 1)

Thanks!

Comment: just saw your comment--so you solved your question above "[s]uppose i want to store...."?

Answer (score 26):

The `data.table` [package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) has syntax that is often [similar to SQL](http://www.carlboettiger.info/2012/02/12/elegant-fast-data-manipulation-with-data-table.html).  The package includes `%like%`, which is a "convenience function for calling regexpr".  Here is an example taken from its help file:

```
## Create the data.table:
DT = data.table(Name=c("Mary","George","Martha"), Salary=c(2,3,4))

## Subset the DT table where the Name column is like "Mar%":
DT[Name %like% "^Mar"]
##      Name Salary
## 1:   Mary      2
## 2: Martha      4
```

Comment: These days, I typically use `%ilike%`, which is a case insensitive version

Comment: For case insensitive search use: `DT[Name %like% "(?i)mar"]` or `DT[Name %ilike% "mar"]`

Answer (score 3):

Something like `regexpr`?

```
> d <- c("Swinging Strike", "In play (run(s))", "In play (out(s) recorded)")
> regexpr('In play', d)
[1] -1  1  1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1  7  7
>
```

or `grep`

```
> grep('In play', d)
[1] 2 3
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `stringr 1.5.0`, you can use [`str_like`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_like.html), which follows the structure of SQL's `LIKE`:

```r
library(stringr)

fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")
str_like(fruit, "app%")
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Not only does it include `%`, but also several other operators (see `?str_like`).

> - Must match the entire string
> - _⁠ matches a single character (like .)
> - ⁠%⁠ matches any number of characters (like ⁠.*⁠)
> - ⁠%⁠ and ⁠_⁠ match literal ⁠%⁠ and ⁠_⁠
> - The match is case insensitive by default